# Проблема получения токена OAuth

Tags: get, token, twitch

Хотелось бы разобраться, как получить токен авторизации для запроса на Twitch API.
В документации API есть вот такой запрос.

```
GET https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize
?client_id=<your client ID>
&redirect_uri=<your registered redirect URI>
&response_type=<type>
&scope=<space-separated list of scopes>
```

В этом запросе мне непонятен redirect_uri.
Токен мне нужен для разовых запросов на API, например для получения ID канала, а не для приложения.